# Do data loads from Amazon S3 to Amazon Redshift go across the Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

If I use copy commands in Amazon Redshift to transfer data from an S3 bucket to Redshift, does this involve connecting to the internet to download objects from the S3 bucket?

Or, are Redshift and the S3 bucket in the same domain network configurations (same IP ranges) and files are transferred between network nodes?